# XFCE session is ruined after installing LXQt

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment

I installed LXQt from Terminal in Debian while I was in Xfce, then switched to LXQt session to see how it looks, however, after switching back to Xfce all window controls (buttons, progress bars, input fields) look classic, like it's all ruined by LXQt. I removed LXQt and LXQt-core but it still isn't fixed. How to remove all LXQt packages and fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your distro is?

Comment: @arochester Sorry, it's Debian.

Comment: have you even tried changing the Style, Icons, Fonts, and/or Settings to something that is acceptable to you?  The Style tab should have a list of dozens of different styles - try one of the `xfce-[version]` styles.  Similarly, the Icons tab will have dozens of different sets of icon styles to choose from (IIRC, "Tango" is the default, try changing it to that).

Comment: BTW, i use the `Clearlooks-Phenix` theme, which is available in the package `clearlooks-phenix-theme` on debian.  I use this because it looks OK (i.e. it doesn't annoy me) and works with both GTK3 and GTK2 apps (some themes only fully support one or the other).  I also use `Tango` for icons, mostly because i've had no reason to change it.  in general, though, i don't care very much about desktop appearance as long as it's not garish or flashy (i also turn off all animations and desktop sounds because they annoy the hell out of me).

Comment: @cas You don't understand me, it doesn't matter what style I choose from Appearance. This classic, Windows 95-like style of buttons and other window controls is still there, I would like to know if there's a way to fix that. It's happening after installing LXQt.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing everything related to LXQt:

```
sudo apt-get remove lxqt*
```